# Getting "IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath when trying to run SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, illegalargumentexception

Getting this error when trying to establish connection with AISSTREAM.IO by running the code as a component of spring application.

Error -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/Asus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.1/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory
at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:592)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:511)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:396)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:124)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:238)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:220)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:171)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:149)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$starting$0(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
at com.demoandy.DemoandyApplication.main(DemoandyApplication.java:10)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54575', transport: 'socket'

I have tried including exclusion for logback in all of the
org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter
for the same but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Read the error. You have `slf4j-simple` on the classpath which interferes, remove the `slf4j-simple` dependency. Nothing more.

Comment: I tried that, and that resulted in no data being streamed. I tried excluding the spring-boot-starter-logger, it starts up the application and then immediately closes it. No data gets streamed

Comment: Which has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Well sorry if I am terrible at communicating. I have next to  no experience with Java and Spring. But I don't really understand how to explain the error